# Can we write down $\mathrm{vec}(Y^{-1})$ in terms of $\mathrm{vec}(Y)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, kronecker-product, vectorization

Lets denote the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)  by $\otimes$  and the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) of a matrix $Y$ by $\mathrm{vec}(Y)$.

Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, where $n\geq m$. What is

$$\mathrm{trace}(BB^TY^{-1}),$$where $\mathrm{vec}(Y)=(A\otimes A-I)^{-1}\mathrm{vec}(BB^T)$? (Assume all eigenvalues of $A$ are larger than $1$)

---

Currently, given specific $A$ and $B$, I have to compute the $\mathrm{vec}(Y)$, then retrieve matrix $Y$, then take the inverse of $Y$ and then compute the $\mathrm{trace}(BB^TY^{-1})$. However, since $Y$ depends on $A$ and $B$, I feel that there must be a way to write down the $\mathrm{trace}(BB^TY^{-1})$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ only. I tried to rewrite it like this:

$$\mathrm{trace}(BB^TY^{-1})=\mathrm{vec}(BB^T)^T\mathrm{vec}(Y^{-1}),$$

but I couldn't find what is the vectorization of the inverse matrix, i.e., $\mathrm{vec}(Y^{-1})$?

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to expressing $Y^{-1}$ in terms of the entries of $Y$. Those expressions are complex (i.e. nonlinear) in general.

Comment: More specifically, if you tried to express ${\rm vec}(Y^{-1})$ as $A \cdot {\rm vec}(Y)$ then the elements of $A$ will be dependent on $Y$ (as the relation is not linear) and hence such an expression is probably not useful. Try a simple example (like 2x2 or 3x3) to see why/how.

Comment: @Florian for $2\times 2$ and $3\times 3$ case, $\mathrm{trace}(BB^TY^{-1})$ is independent of $B$. However, for larger dimensions $\mathrm{trace}(BB^TY^{-1})$ depends on $B$.

Comment: I thought the point was the dependence on $Y$, not $B$.

Comment: @Florian I mean that trace depends only depends on $B$, thus it is easy to calculate the trace in terms of $A$ only. However for larger dimension trace cannot be obtained in terms of $A$ only.